# Generate HTML on saving with text variables

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, html-preprocessor

I use VSCode, and I have a lot of different static HTML pages on different languages.

I have HTML like this:

```
<div>Some text here</div>
<p>and there</p>
```

There are 100+ places with different text strings that I need to change tag-by-tag if I want to paste some translate. So, it's very inconvenient to look a new tags each time.

Are there any ways (preprocessors/extensions/anything else) to place text separately of text-tags, and put it in HTML on the page saving?

Something like:

```
<div>{{ translates.some1 }}</div>
<p>{{ translates.some2 }}</p>

<translates>
some1: "Some text here",
some2: "and there",
</translates>
```

Comment: Many many internationalization (i18n) frameworks exist

Comment: and if you use such a framework write a script that generates the static pages for each language using a set of templates

Comment: I know i18n, it's good for SPA, but I need a static pages. Sure, I can write my own script that can do it. I asked are there any ready-make solutions.

Comment: Do you have a separate html file for each language?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes. Separate static html's